# Same material different opacity

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have thousands of meshes with identical material, but with different opacity.
Is there a way to reuse the material among them?

Comment: If it's about thousands of the same objects, then I would use `InstancedMesh`, setting opacity per instance.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, it is the intended way to use different instances of your material. `three.js` will ensure to reuse a single shader program even if opacity values vary.

Comment: Indeed, and this can be verified by inspecting `WebGLRenderer.info.programs.length`, which indicates the number of shader programs in use, and `WebGLRenderer.info.programs[i].usedTimes`, which indicates the number of `Mesh`es using program _i_.  [Demo here](https://codepen.io/pnichols04/pen/KKXjVxd).  (Nonetheless, thousands of `Mesh`es does suggest that instancing may be appropriate, as @prisoner849 mentioned.)